# How to replace icon in datePicker using Angular5 Material?

Tags: datepicker, icons, angular5

I have defined a `datePicker` using Angular5, but I would need to replace icon within `<mat-datepicker-toggle>`

Taking a look into documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) it seems that should be enough using directive `matDatepickerToggleIcon`, but it seems that it does not take effect and default icon is still displayed.

The code I have is the following:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput 
        [(ngModel)]="varDateFrom" 
        [matDatepicker]="DatepickerFrom"                    
        placeholder="Date From"
        name="DateFrom">                                
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="DatepickerFrom">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
     </mat-datepicker-toggle>                   
     <mat-datepicker #DatepickerFrom></mat-datepicker></mat-form-field>
```

Any idea why directive is not working?

Many thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way, removing `mat-datepicker-toggle` and adding an external icon:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput 
    [(ngModel)]="varDateFrom" 
    [matDatepicker]="DatepickerFrom"                    
    placeholder="Date From"
    name="DateFrom">                                
  <mat-datepicker #DatepickerFrom></mat-datepicker>
  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" (click)="picker.open()"></i>
</mat-form-field>
```